# Performance issues with J2EE application on JBoss 7.1.1Final

Tags: jsf-2, jboss7.x, jboss-weld

recently we have deployed J2EE application on JBoss 7.1.1Final. This application is using CDI (Weld implementation), JSF 2.1 (Mojarra), Seam 3 and Hibernate 4. When we're experiencing higher load, the application becomes slow. Even after the load drops down a little, the responsiveness remains poorer. The CPU utilization is around 300% on 8 core machine. So it seems that CPU is not a bottleneck. I also check wether database or IO might be a bottleneck and it is not. There is also enough memory, the JVM uses at most 2GB out of provided 3GB. I don't really know where else to look. When the server has high CPU utilization, I dumped threads that are using CPU most and it seems that there is some issue either with Weld or JSF, here are some of these thread dumps that occur frequently when the responsiveness is low:

```
 java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:143)
    at org.jboss.weld.context.cache.RequestScopedBeanCache.isActive(RequestScopedBeanCache.java:37)
    at org.jboss.seam.faces.environment.SeamExternalContext$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getInitParameter(SeamExternalContext$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.popComponentFromEL(UIComponent.java:1944)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.publishAfterViewEvents(UIComponentBase.java:2218)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.publishAfterViewEvents(UIComponentBase.java:2206)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.publishAfterViewEvents(UIComponentBase.java:2206)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.publishAfterViewEvents(UIComponentBase.java:2206)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.publishAfterViewEvents(UIComponentBase.java:2206)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.publishAfterViewEvents(UIComponentBase.java:2206)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.publishAfterViewEvents(UIComponentBase.java:2206)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.publishAfterViewEvents(UIComponentBase.java:2206)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.publishAfterViewEvents(UIComponentBase.java:2206)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.doPostAddProcessing(UIComponentBase.java:1883)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.setParent(UIComponentBase.java:400)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase$ChildrenList.add(UIComponentBase.java:2635)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase$ChildrenList.add(UIComponentBase.java:2607)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentSupport.addComponent(ComponentSupport.java:574)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.addComponentToView(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:311)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:211)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:308)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:367)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:346)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:199)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.DecorateHandler.apply(DecorateHandler.java:145)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
    at org.richfaces.view.facelets.html.BehaviorsAddingComponentHandlerWrapper.applyNextHandler(BehaviorsAddingComponentHandlerWrapper.java:53)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:195)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)


 java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.lang.Thread.currentThread(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:143)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.InterceptionDecorationContext.pop(InterceptionDecorationContext.java:43)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.InterceptionDecorationContext.endInterceptorContext(InterceptionDecorationContext.java:93)
    at org.jboss.seam.faces.environment.SeamExternalContext$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getInitParameter(SeamExternalContext$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.pushComponentToEL(UIComponent.java:1860)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.publishAfterViewEvents(UIComponentBase.java:2200)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.publishAfterViewEvents(UIComponentBase.java:2206)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.publishAfterViewEvents(UIComponentBase.java:2206)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.publishAfterViewEvents(UIComponentBase.java:2206)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.publishAfterViewEvents(UIComponentBase.java:2206)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.publishAfterViewEvents(UIComponentBase.java:2206)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.publishAfterViewEvents(UIComponentBase.java:2206)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.doPostAddProcessing(UIComponentBase.java:1883)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.setParent(UIComponentBase.java:400)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase$ChildrenList.add(UIComponentBase.java:2635)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase$ChildrenList.add(UIComponentBase.java:2607)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentSupport.addComponent(ComponentSupport.java:574)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.addComponentToView(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:311)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:211)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
    at org.richfaces.view.facelets.html.BehaviorsAddingComponentHandlerWrapper.applyNextHandler(BehaviorsAddingComponentHandlerWrapper.java:53)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:195)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.DefineHandler.applyDefinition(DefineHandler.java:107)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:178)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext$TemplateManager.apply(DefaultFaceletContext.java:395)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeDefinition(DefaultFaceletContext.java:366)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.InsertHandler.apply(InsertHandler.java:112)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
    at org.richfaces.view.facelets.html.BehaviorsAddingComponentHandlerWrapper.applyNextHandler(BehaviorsAddingComponentHandlerWrapper.java:53)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:195)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.ViewHandler.apply(ViewHandler.java:182)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:86)

   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at java.lang.ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap$Entry.<init>(ThreadLocal.java:276)
at java.lang.ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap.set(ThreadLocal.java:443)
at java.lang.ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap.access$100(ThreadLocal.java:261)
at java.lang.ThreadLocal.setInitialValue(ThreadLocal.java:164)
at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:150)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.InterceptionDecorationContext.push(InterceptionDecorationContext.java:58)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.InterceptionDecorationContext.startInterceptorContext(InterceptionDecorationContext.java:97)
at org.jboss.seam.faces.environment.SeamExternalContext$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getInitParameter(SeamExternalContext$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.pushComponentToEL(UIComponent.java:1860)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.publishAfterViewEvents(UIComponentBase.java:2200)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.publishAfterViewEvents(UIComponentBase.java:2206)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.publishAfterViewEvents(UIComponentBase.java:2206)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.publishAfterViewEvents(UIComponentBase.java:2206)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.publishAfterViewEvents(UIComponentBase.java:2206)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.publishAfterViewEvents(UIComponentBase.java:2206)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.publishAfterViewEvents(UIComponentBase.java:2206)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.publishAfterViewEvents(UIComponentBase.java:2206)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.publishAfterViewEvents(UIComponentBase.java:2206)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.publishAfterViewEvents(UIComponentBase.java:2206)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.publishAfterViewEvents(UIComponentBase.java:2206)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.doPostAddProcessing(UIComponentBase.java:1883)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.setParent(UIComponentBase.java:400)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase$ChildrenList.add(UIComponentBase.java:2635)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase$ChildrenList.add(UIComponentBase.java:2607)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentSupport.addComponent(ComponentSupport.java:574)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.addComponentToView(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:311)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:211)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.ViewHandler.apply(ViewHandler.java:182)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:308)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:367)
```

Any ideas what might be a problem?

Thanks

Comment: What tool are you using to profile the application? Look for the application classes in your stacktraces before jumping into any org classes.

Comment: I'm using JProfiler, but I don't attach it to production machine as it takes too much resources. I have my own script that is printing out stack traces of threads are are using a lot of CPU. I didn't find any troubles my code as the stack traces never show some method calls in my own system. It seems it's usually hanging when it's rendering response. That is JSF.